# How to install django-channels in ubuntu?

Tags: django, python-3.x, macos, pip

I have tried to install django channels using this command.

`pip install -U channels`

but am getting this error

> Downloading/unpacking channels   Downloading
>   channels-2.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl Cleaning up... Exception:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/praneet/pral/myvenv/lib/python-wheels/setuptools-3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources.py",
>   line 2482, in _dep_map
>       return self.**dep_map   File "/home/praneet/pral/myvenv/lib/python-wheels/setuptools-3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources.py",
>   line 2344, in __getattr**
>       raise AttributeError(attr) AttributeError: _DistInfoDistribution__dep_map
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/praneet/pral/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py",
>   line 122, in main
>       status = self.run(options, args)   File "/home/praneet/pral/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py",
>   line 278, in run
>       requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)   File
>   "/home/praneet/pral/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/req.py",
>   line 1266, in prepare_files
>       req_to_install.extras):   File "/home/praneet/pral/myvenv/lib/python-wheels/setuptools-3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources.py",
>   line 2291, in requires
>       dm = self._dep_map   File "/home/praneet/pral/myvenv/lib/python-wheels/setuptools-3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources.py",
>   line 2484, in _dep_map
>       self.__dep_map = self._compute_dependencies()   File "/home/praneet/pral/myvenv/lib/python-wheels/setuptools-3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources.py",
>   line 2508, in _compute_dependencies
>       parsed = next(parse_requirements(distvers))   File "/home/praneet/pral/myvenv/lib/python-wheels/setuptools-3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources.py",
>   line 2605, in parse_requirements
>       line, p, specs = scan_list(VERSION,LINE_END,line,p,(1,2),"version spec")   File
>   "/home/praneet/pral/myvenv/lib/python-wheels/setuptools-3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources.py",
>   line 2573, in scan_list
>       raise ValueError("Expected "+item_name+" in",line,"at",line[p:]) ValueError: ('Expected version spec in', 'asgiref ~=2.1', 'at', '
>   ~=2.1')
>
> Storing debug log for failure in /home/praneet/.pip/pip.log

Comment: I am installing first time the channels

Comment: What's your pip version? Please upgrade your pip version.

Comment: This is the problem with pkg_resources. Please upgrade your pip `sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip` Let me know if this works ?

Comment: WHat should be included in installed apps for django-channels

Comment: Waitaminute are you saying is that solution worked and now you are having another question ?

Answer (score 1):

I was also stuck with same issue.

Now,I have fixed it by installing following packages:

python2

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev python-pip libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev
```

python3

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev python3-pip libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev
```